# Flutter: CupertinoActivityIndicator non working anymore

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I have just went through an upgrade of flutter and all my dependencies and CupertinoActivityIndicator() does not work anymore, ie it does not show up and animate

Does anyone know what is the reason?

Here is my code

```
class LittleProgressIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!appData.isIOS) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: kColorPrimary,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(kColorAccent),
      );
    } else {
      return CupertinoActivityIndicator(
        animating: true,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: If you would like some help you have to shows your code. It would also help to tells us what version of Flutter you are using. Check the guidelines for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask